# Leiningen install for Windows error

Tags: windows, clojure, leiningen

I'm very unskilled when it comes to the command prompt, so I tried to download Lein through the Windows installer that's on the website. It almost installs, but then I get this error at the very end of the install:

"Failed to update file: C:\Users\.lein\profiles.clj.
 Ensure that :java-cmd is set to: 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\java.exe' in your 
:user profile. 
 Result: Ran; Code: 1".

What could cause this to happen? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you only have the JRE installed instead of the JDK.
Open a command and enter "javac". Most probably the OS cannot find it. If so, download one here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

Afterwards add the JDK_INSTALL\bin location to your windows path. This should fix it.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I do have the JDK installed for my computer, however. Can you explain what you mean by adding JDK_INSTALL\bin location to my path?

Comment: This links explains how to set the path: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm Usually the jdk is installed in a location like this: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51 So you will have to add: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin to the path

Comment: Nevermind! I got it to work. Thank you for your help, though! What I did was just uninstall Lein, reinstall it, and use the most recent JDK that was available (I think I was using 1.7_21 rather than 1.7_51 or something like that.) Thanks again